# Secure and HttpOnly for SMSESSION cookie breaks the login functionality

Tags: security, authentication, siteminder, cookie-httponly

Because of the vulnerabilities in Security Scans(SCABBA) done for our applications, we added secure and HttpOnly to SMESSION cookie. Now we are facing the issue like when i am redirecting from one application to another(all are under single sign on) some time Session get invalidated withing 5-10 min. we are redirecting to Login page.

I hope SMSESSION fix we did is causing these problems but nor sure on it. Some where i got the below info

**smsession cookie generated by siteminder is always encrypted format and is also highly secure manner.
We can have secure & http-only flags to the siteminder cookies implemented but there may be some functionality issues after implementing these flags to the cookies likewise.
(a) Seamless will break on moving from HTTP to HTTPs or vice versa** (we have all https only)
**(b) There may be few session upholding issues 
(c) Logout functionality may break. These were few of the breakage which we experienced in last few cases.**

Can anyone have idea on it?

Thanks in advance

-Regards,
Raviteja Koditiwada

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS is all or nothing.  If an application divulges its session id over HTTP then that account can be compromised,  and this is why [Facebook is now entirely HTTPS](http://www.forbes.com/sites/kashmirhill/2011/01/26/after-mark-zuckerbergs-account-is-hacked-facebook-ups-its-security-measures/).  Leaking a session id over an insecure channel is a violation of [OWASP Insufficient Transport Layer Security](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Periodic_Table_of_Vulnerabilities_-_Insufficient_Transport_Layer_Protection) and one of the OWASP Top 10 most common web application vulnerabilities.

A web application can use the `secure` cookie flag to prevent plain-text HTTP requests from containing the session id. Therefore any authenticated request sent by the browser must be over HTTPS, **and this is required for security**.

The `secure` and `httponly` cookie flags are **important**.  Tell your vendor to fix this OWASP top 10 vulnerability,  and to look for other OWASP top 10 violations in their software. Using [HTTP Strict Transport Security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) is also a very good idea.